# Chrome 95 on CentOS 7.9

Tags: centos, chrome

I have a medium size Selenium grid with nodes based on CentOS 7.9 (a couple hundred nodes).  Using yum-cron, the nodes are updating their browser version daily (the requirement is to target the latest browser). This morning, chrome 95 could not be installed, because it has dependency on glibc 2.18, which I understand will never be available on CentOS 7.

I am not in a position to upgrade/change OS version on the nodes at this time. Short of getting chromium source and recompiling against glibc 2.18 - is there any way to get latest chrome to run on CentOS 7.9?

Answer (score 0):

There's an official snap for Chromium, available here : https://snapcraft.io/chromium

The current `latest/stable` channel release is 94.0.4606.81, but you can select a different channel and get newer versions.  I just tried the `latest/edge` channel on a CentOS 7 machine and it installed 96.0.4664.9 which appears to work OK and presumably will have whatever patches are on 95.x as well.

Hopefully 95 will become the stable version soon too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the official release 95.0.4638.69-1 is now compatible with CentOS 7. I had the same issue as the OP on the first release of Chrome 95, but 95.0.4638.69-1 now installs fine with yum.